# dictionary calculating incorrectly producing integers

Tags: vba

I have a function that creates a dictionary, on the key I have a unique identified, whereas on the value I would like to do a sumif, however the values are being retrieved as integers with E- and as a result I cannot do what I need to do with the values, any way I could get .000245 as a result in the svalue?

```
Public Sub Createdic(ws As Worksheet, ary, dic)
Dim y, skey, svalue
Dim key As Variant

    'Early binding: add reference to MS Scripting Runtime

    On Error Resume Next
    'populate fund list

    For y = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If ary(y) <> "" Then
            skey = Trim(ary(y))
            svalue = ((WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.range(letter(ws, "Security Name") & ":" & letter(ws, "Security Name")), ary(y), ws.range(letter(ws, "Base Market Value") & ":" & letter(ws, "Base Market Value"))) / Sheets("Input Sheet").range("TNA").value))
            dic.Add svalue, skey
        End If
    Next y

End Sub
```

now
svalue = 4.20391436648078E-05

what I would like 
svalue = 0.004203194%

Comment: Have you tried changing the column format to Number?

Comment: Would help to show an example of the output: "integers with E" just sounds like scientific notation....

Comment: Just goes to zero when I do

Comment: @TimWilliams I have edited it now

Comment: Format$(sValue,"0.000000000%")

Comment: @braX is correct. You can use the Format instead of Format$ as well. Thanks